# How do I make Google Chrome open Incognito by default?

Tags: google-chrome

In previous Ubuntus (GNOME, not unity) I could add "--incognito" to the end of the executable file command of Chrome to make Incognito default.

I cannot find an executable file for Chrome in 12.04. How do I make Incognito default for Chrome in 12.04?