# How to start Chrome always in "Incognito Mode"?

Tags: google-chrome

So... I found a solution to be able to open Chrome on 12.04 in Incognito Mode by default ([How do I make Google Chrome open Incognito by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159630/how-do-i-make-google-chrome-open-incognito-by-default-in-12-04)).

I can't seem to get it to open consistently in Incognito Mode with all the pages I have set to load on startup e.g. In OS X, I open Chrome, which defaults to Incognito Mode and loads all the websites I have set in the "Open a specific page or set of pages" preference. In Ubuntu I can't replicate that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/159630/10698

Comment: I'm not even sure why this is closed as bug report...

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu/Linux **unless you edit the `.desktop` file it won't work**. Run the following:

```
sed 's/\/google-chrome/\/google-chrome --incognito/g' /usr/share/applications/google*.desktop
```

Is not efficient but will do the work.